# How to pass Azure DevOps pipeline variable into command of 'Run Azure Data Explorer Command'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-explorer, kql

We use these Azure Kusto Command tasks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/devops

How can we pass variables into the kusto commands (like EventColdStorageConnectionString in the example)?

```
.create-or-alter external table EventData(['version']:string,messageid:string,serial:string,datetimelocal:datetime,datetimeutc:datetime,cspid:string,cspname:string,ownerid:string,ownername:string,location:string,countrycode:string,softwareversion:string,['configuration']:string,model:string,severityname:string,number:string,eventname:string,categoryname:string,stateful:bool,index:real,module:string,source:string,internaltext:string, fingerprint: long)
    kind = storage
    partition by (Model: string = model, Date: datetime = startofday (datetimeutc))
    pathformat = ('Events/' Model '/' datetime_pattern('yyyy/MM/dd', Date))
    dataformat = parquet
    (h@'$EventColdStorageConnectionString') --> insert variable here
    with (includeHeaders = 'None', folder = 'ColdStorage');
```

I've already tried to access variables like in powershell scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps:

1 define variable in pipeline
[image: define variable]

2 use variable `EventColdStorageConnectionString` in your script
Here is script sample:

```
    dataformat = parquet
    (
      h@'$(EventColdStorageConnectionString)'
     )
```

3  I test it in my pipeline and it can parse the variable `EventColdStorageConnectionString` successfully.

[image: run result]

Comment: Thanks for your help. We got it work, but only with inline commands. With file commands it does not replace the variables. For file commands we use a task [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SETISAS.replace-variables-in-file&targetId=a2fce0c8-108c-44f9-aab4-e7a2702c0d56](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SETISAS.replace-variables-in-file&targetId=a2fce0c8-108c-44f9-aab4-e7a2702c0d56) which replaces all the variables in artifact file and run it after replace.
[https://imgur.com/a/c4OalhN](https://imgur.com/a/c4OalhN)

Comment: Yes,it is. It seems like that variables in file command can't be parsed.